# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Bootstrap Website with a dropdown box in the Navbar. When the Navbar is in collapse mode. The dropdown menu is not responding
Does anyone know why this would happen

The website can be found at http://horizonarb.co.uk/index.html

The code is as follows;

Many thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Horizon Arboriculture</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <script src="js/googleFonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

     <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

     <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <small>MENU</small>
                </button>

             <a href=""><img src="img/front/HorizonArb_Tree_Transparent.png" class="noResize"></a>

            </div> <!-- class="navbar-header" -->

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">

                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Crown Thinning</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Crown Lifting</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Crown Reduction</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div> <!-- class="collapse navbar-collapse" -->

        </div> <!-- class="container" -->

      </div> <!--  class="navbar navbar-default" -->    



      <div class="container" id="topContainer">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 center marginTopThirty">

                <img src="img/front/HorizonArb_Transparent.png" width="70%">


            </div>







    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? It is working for me in FF.

Comment: It doesn't work in my FF. Are you trying it when it is phone size?

Comment: It does. It has vertical scroll though. That is probably the problem.

Comment: Is your website how you want the menu to appear, or do you want it to appear like in the Bootstrap docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dropdown is opening and closing, but it's hidden from view by the container. The following CSS should fix that:

```
.navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible; /* Bootstrap default is "auto" */
}
```

Comment: I saw this, and was going to comment but this is in the bootstrap styling to be auto, this shouldn't need changing should it? Looking at how the dropdown is working on the OP's site, it doesn't look like it's been coded correctly.. which may be the issue.

Comment: The [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) illustrate a dropdown within a collapsed navbar, but their navbar is accordion-style while OP's is a row of buttons. My theory is the Bootstrap developers envisioned a different use case than what OP has implemented.